# Is UDP (in Java or otherwise) full duplex by default?

Tags: java, sockets, networking, udp, duplex

I.e. am I able to read from and write to the same socket using two different threads, given that I'm doing all communication in the form of datagrams?

Comment: How does the code for this work?

Is it fine to create one datagram socket, and use socket.receive as well as socket.send from two different threads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UDP IS in fact fully duplex.

You can have a server listening from as well as writing to the same socket

Answer (score 4):

UDP, in the right circumstances, *can* be considered fully duplex, but by itself, it is not, whereas TCP, on the other hand, is always fully duplex.

UDP is a fire-and-forget, best-effort protocol, but the upper layers can use it in a fully duplex fashion.

TCP requires handshaking and other two-way communication.